# Saving as plain text

Tags: vba

I have a code which guys on here helped me with.
This issue is it saves to a shared drive and the info in the cells is still linked to the master copy of the workbook. Is there way to save it as text and not a link?

```
Sub Sample()
   Dim i As Long
   Dim DateString As String
   Dim wbName As String

If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
Else
    Select Case ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
        Case 51:
            FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        Case 52:
            If Application.ActiveWorkbook.HasVBProject Then
                FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
            Else
                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            End If
        Case 56:
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
        Case Else:
            FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
    End Select
End If

'~~> Get file name without extension
wbName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
'~~> Final folder path
FolderPath = "F:\Orders" & "\" & wbName

'~~> Check if folder exists. If it doesn't then create it
If Not FolderExists(FolderPath) Then MkDir FolderPath

'~~> Loop through the worksheets and save them
For i = 3 To 18
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Visible Then
        RenameAndSaveSheet ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Here is the renameandsave

```
Private Sub RenameAndSaveSheet(ws As Worksheet)
Dim FlName As String
Dim wbNew As Workbook
With ws
    .Copy
    .Name = .Range("B1").Value2
    
    FlName = FolderPath & "\" & ws.Name & FileExtStr
    
    Set wbNew = Application.Workbooks.Item(Application.Workbooks.Count)
    wbNew.SaveAs FlName, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    wbNew.Close False
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you show RenameAndSaveSheet  also.

Comment: maybe add a `ws.UsedRange.Value = ws.UsedRange.Value` after `.Copy`?

Comment: `.Name = .Range("B1").Value2` seems like it would rename the original sheet, not the copy

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to break all the links make a Function that does that:

```
' Break all Excel Links found in given worksheet
Public Sub BreakAllLinks(ByVal thisWorkbook As Workbook)
    Dim theseLinks As Variant
    theseLinks = thisWorkbook.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
    If Not IsEmpty(theseLinks) Then
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To UBound(theseLinks)
            thisWorkbook.BreakLink Name:=theseLinks(i), Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Then you call that before you save it:

```
Public Sub RenameAndSaveSheet(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim FlName As String
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    With ws
        .Copy
        .Name = .Range("B1").Value2
        
        FlName = FolderPath & "\" & .Name & FileExtStr
    End With
    
    Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
    BreakAllLinks wbNew
    wbNew.SaveAs FlName, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    wbNew.Close False
End Sub
```